# A number n is not a Prime no and lies between 1 to 301,how many such numbers are there which is not divisible by 2,3,5,7.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> A number n is not a prime and lies between $1$ and $301$, how many such numbers are there which are not divisible by $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$?
>
> a) $6$
>   b) $8$
>   c) $10$
>   d) $12$

My approach:

Multiplication of prime with itself or other primes gives composite numbers. So

11*11=121

11*13=143

11*17=187

11*19=209

11*23=253

11*29=319 which is not in range of 1-301 so we cant conider it

13*13=169

13*17=221

13*19=247

13*23=299

17*17=289

17*19=323 which is not in range of 1-301 so we can't consider it

So total possible numbers are $10$ and option c) is the right one.

Are there any better approaches to this problem?

Comment: It's a fine approach. I can't think of a better one...

Comment: Define "between". To many people, "between 1 and 301" would include 1 and 301 themselves. 1 is not a prime and not divisible by 2, 3, 5, 7.

Comment: @hvd If we allow for 1, the number is 11, which is not one of the answer options, hence we do not allow for 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to formalise this a bit is to note that $\sqrt {301}\lt 18$ so there must be at least one prime factor less than $18$. Consider these in turn:

The highest values you need to consider are $$17\times \left\lfloor \frac {301}{17}\right\rfloor =17 \times 17$$$$13\times \left\lfloor \frac {301}{13}\right\rfloor =13 \times 23$$where $23$ is the largest prime (only if the second factor is $\gt 121$ does the question of three factors arise) and $$11\times \left\lfloor \frac {301}{11}\right\rfloor =11 \times 27$$ where $23$ is the largest prime.

---

Original version had $323$ as the target number

---

This might save you a little work, because it identifies the highest values first, and once you have done this, you know that all the lower values work without having to do the multiplications.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is valid and probably the best possible.

Of course, a composite number could also be constructed from the product of three or more primes, so to be really pedantic one might also look at $11 \cdot 11 \cdot 11$ but since this is way bigger than $301$, we needn't bother with any 3-products (in this case).